# How can I receive link from Drawable?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a function like this:

```
 fromColorResAndUrl(@ColorRes int colorRes, String imageUrl)
```

Now I call it in this way:

```
fromColorResAndUrl(R.color.blue,
                 "http://www.example.com/wallpaper.jpg");
```

You can see it use an external image link.

I want use local image link. so I save `'wallpaper.jpg'` in `res/drawable`.

Now I want to know how can put that in the function?

I try `file:///android_asset/drawable/wallpaper.jpg` but no success!

Answer (score 0):

Use `R.drawable.wallpaper`, as seen on [Drawable Resources on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Also, if you import drawables, it is recommended to have them scaled for each phone size. I recommend using [android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/winterDroid/android-drawable-importer-intellij-plugin), it is really fast and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

The `file:///android_asset/...` URLs can only find resources in the `assets` folder, so if you use `file:///android_asset/drawable/wallpaper.jpg` then you must put `wallpaper.jpg` inside of the `assets/drawable/` folder, which is not the default location for drawables.

Answer (score 0):

Strip out the URL string so you only have the name of the file without the extension

```
String fileName = "wallpaper"
```

Then get the int resource value:

```
int imgR = getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

then get your image with: `getResources().getDrawable(imgR)`.
As an example for an ImageView:

```
try {

    yourImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(imgR)
    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
        int defaultR = getResources().getIdentifier(yourfallbackimg, "drawable", getPackageName())
        yourImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(defaultR))
    }
```

Use a try catch just in case you don't have filename being returned, this way you'll have a default image instead of a crash.

**EDIT**

check http://pastebin.com/yN3zUciN

Comment: Thanks I try `String fileName = "wallpaper_51";
                int imgR = getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "drawable", getPackageName());
                ImageView yourImageView;
                String str = yourImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(imgR));` But I got void error

Comment: Why did you write String str = ImageView.setImageDrawable?

Comment: I know it's wrong. I want get  URL of image as string to use in that function. I want to know how can I change it to string now

Comment: The url or the filename of the URL? You should already have the url as you're the one setting it. For the filename only use the fileName variable. Check my updated post link